# Azure Mobile App node.js backend Android client - 50 row limit

Tags: android, node.js, azure

I have been trying to get over the 50 rows result returned by Azure mobile app, but no success so far. I have tried the following:
a. Top(100), Skip(100) -> this solution is not useful to me in my context.
b. Someone suggested to increase the pageSize to 200 in the app.js which I tried - but this did not work. I still got only 50 rows returned.

Any pointers on how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.
- Sankar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the source code of table operations of Mobile Apps in node.js, the [read operation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/blob/master/src/express/tables/operations.js#L9) ultimately receives `context.query` which is a [`queryjs`](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/module-queryjs_Query.html) object, which contains a `take()` function which can limit the number of items returned to the specified number.

Additionally, the `take()` function is contained in the mobile app server sdk, so it doesn't work on your client end code.

You can do some modification on your Easy Tables scripts, E.G.

```
table.read(function (context) {
    context.query.take(100);
    return context.execute();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. For Android - Node.js on Azure, this is the right answer. Unfortunately, this is not documented anywhere properly and could not find this in any of the forums. Thanks Gary for your timely help.

Answer (score 3):

In app.js add the following line:

```
var mobileApp = azureMobileApps({
    ....,
    pageSize: 200
});
```

Comment: Damn, this answer should have been marked as correct. Thank you