# increase max count azure mobile services android

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services

I am doing android-azure mobile app offline sync. and currently use this code to pull table

```
table.pull(query).get();
```

however with this the max top is always 50 which causes many calls.

now to set top i read, you have to do ,

```
QueryOperations().fields().top()
```

but if i do not have any conditions then query variable will be null, and hence I am not sure how i set "top" parameter.

I am very much new in android. so if question is not good, feel free to edit. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Azure offical tutorial [`How to use the Azure Mobile Apps SDK for Android`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library#a-namequeryaquery-a-backend-table), it said as below in the subsection `Return data in pages`.

> **Return data in pages**
>
> Data is ALWAYS returned in pages. The maximum number of records returned is set by the server. If the client requests more records, then the server returns the maximum number of records. ***By default, the maximum page size on the server is 50 records.***

And a tip shows.

> Tip
>
> Choosing the right page size is a balance between memory usage while the request is happening, bandwidth usage and delay in receiving the data completely. The default (50 records) is suitable for all devices. If you exclusively operate on larger memory devices, increase up to 500. We have found that increasing the page size beyond 500 records results in unacceptable delays and large memory issues.

So if you want to change the maxmium page size, you need to set it on the backend of Azure Mobile Apps via NodeJs/C# code. The client SDK could not do it.

There was an existing SO thread [Azure Mobile App node.js backend Android client - 50 row limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759501/azure-mobile-app-node-js-backend-android-client-50-row-limit/38762019#38762019) which has a similar question with yours, you can refer to its answer to resolve yours if you were using NodeJS in your backend.

Hope it helps.